# Using namespace std?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I included the line `using namespace std;`on top of my code. Now consider the declaration   `int a,b,c;`.Is above code an equivalent to `int std::a,std::b,std::c;`? If so, consider the following example:

If I declared(defined) a namespace `Hi` after the line `using namespace std;`.
Is `Hi` a part of `std` i.e .., am I supposed to use `Hi` as `std::Hi`?

I'm a beginner .

Comment: No. You only use the stuff from the namespace. The `std` namespace contains stuff like `cout` and `string` and a *LOT* of other stuff.

Comment: Both are no. And you need to read books instead of asking too basic questions.

Comment: No, with the 'using namespace' statement you enable symbols from the std namespace to be used without the namespace qualifier.

Comment: @liliscent He might just be doing it as a hobby, in which case a book isn't really a great idea.

Comment: @KidDoesCodingAndHasNoFriends: That is the opposite of true.

Comment: I strongly disagree, @KidDoesCodingAndHasNoFriends . Having good references saves a ton of time, even a single book. Without a good guided reference you often lack the correct terminology required to find tutorials or online reference materials via web searches and lack the frame of reference required to tell good materials from bad. Of course that requires finding a good book in the first place. [Fortunately Stack Overflow maintains a curated list of trusted reference material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @KidDoesCodingAndHasNoFriends I miss those times when I was a kid, had programming only as a hobby, and had enough time to read all those fancy books about C++ programming :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is above code an equivalent to `int std::a,std::b,std::c;`

No.  A `using namespace` statement means that your code can use members of that namespace without having to qualify them with the namespace's name.

For example, say you have a `#include <string>` statement followed by a `using namespace std;` statement.  You can then refer to the `std::string` class as just `string` instead.

Or, say you have a `#include <iostream>` statement followed by a `using namespace std;` statement.  You can then refer to the `std::cin` and `std::cout` objects as just `cin` and `cout`, respectively.

Simply `using` a namespace does not add anything to that namespace.  It is a way of bringing content from the specified namespace into the calling namespace.

> If I declared(defined) a namespace `Hi` after the line `using namespace std;`. Is `Hi` a part of `std`

No.  To do that, `Hi` would have to be declared inside of a `namespace std` block, eg:

```
namespace std {
    namespace Hi {
        ...
    }
}
```

But, [that is undefined behavior (except in special cases)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std), as you are generally not allowed to add things to the `std` namespace.

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no need for `std::Hi`.The variables you declare are not in `std` namespace. The `std` generally contains common language facilities such as `cout`, `cin`, `string` etc.